# can't access lexical declaration before initialization during Angular service worker update

Tags: angular, service, updates, worker

I develop an Angular app that uses a service worker (ngsw-config.json etc...).
I'm testing the Angular service worker update mechanism.

I get this error message in browser console when a new app version is available on my server. It seems to happen between the `SwUpdate.VERSION_DETECTED` and the `SwUpdate.VERSION_READY` events (the worker never triggers this last event, probably because of the error). Precisely, during or after the SW downloads the new `main.js` and `ngsw.json` but in the old `main.js`, not in the new one.
The app seems updated when I restart it.

When the app is up to date, no error occurs.

Interesting fact : most of the time, the exact message is `can't access lexical declaration 'o' before initialization` but sometimes, it's `can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization` (note the a instead of the o).

It's hard to know where the error happens, it doesn't occur under VSCode debugger and the app is minified.

Comment: Error seems to happen if I change (in the code processing the `SwUpdate.VERSION_READY` event) :
`console.log("version is ready");`
to
`const msg = "version is ready";
console.log(msg);`
How come?

Comment: One thing that explains my problems is that the Angular service using SwUpdate was not called. But that does not explain the weird messages...